# Break through the speed limit of 1.5 Mbps for Bluetooth tethering

Tags: usb, wifi, bluetooth

My mobile phone brand is Xiaomi Poco X3 NFC and I want to share my mobile internet data with my PC using the Bluetooth tethering feature because tethering over Bluetooth consumes less charge from my mobile battery. According to my tests, Bluetooth tethering shares mobile internet with a maximum speed of 1.5 Mbps.

**Is there a solution to remove this speed limit?** How can I test the maximum internet transfer speed from my mobile Bluetooth tethering?

Note that I don't like to use USB tethering because I can't prevent my mobile from charging through USB after tethering and it may damage the battery. And I don't like to use WiFi tethering too because it has high battery usage and has a lot of connection failure.

Comment: Bluetooth is not designed for high speed transfers and actually got slower in newer versions to prioritize saving energy. It is slow *because* it uses less power. If you want more speed you will use more power, and that is exactly what the WiFi tethering option is meant to be used for. There is no way to go faster than the theoretical 2mbps on modern Bluteooth.